# Screen turns black after opening storyboard in Xcode 5.1.1

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, crash, storyboard

I'm using a simple storyboard in my iOS 7 iPhone-project, containing only one UIViewController and GLKViewController embedded in one navigation controller. When i try to open the storyboard as Interface Builder, the entire screen turns black and only the cursor is visible. I can't do anything besides moving the cursor, until i restart my mac. OS X Version is 10.9.3.

As a "workaround" i figured out, that I can open the storyboard as Source Code. When i add some nonsense to targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch", then try to open it as Interface Builder I get rightly an error message. When i open it again as Source Code, remove the nonsense, I can now open it via Interface Builder and everything works fine until this happens again after some days.

Thanks for any help regarding this annoying issue.

Answer (score 2):

I just had the same issue.

I'm not really sure what did the trick in my case but what I did was:

1. Removing Account from "Xcode - Preferences - Accounts" - I'm rather sure that didn't help
2. Performing Clean-up of the project
3. Opening the Storyboard as Source Code
4. Opening the Storyboard with External Editor

After these steps I just tried to open the storyboard with an interface builder and it worked.

I know that basically only point 2 might have helped but I'm writing all the steps because I can't reproduce the problem to test it again.

Hope it will help someone.

**#EDIT**

I just had the same issue again (after one day).
To be able to open Storyboard with Interface Builder I just had to do two steps:

1. Click on it with right mouse button -> open as -> Source code
2. Click on it with right mouse button -> open as -> Interface Builder - Storyboard

Possibly first step was not needed.
Maybe there is a difference when you just normally try to open the storyboard and when you do it by "Open as"...

Comment: That is what i described as my "workaround", adding nonsense to the source code of the storyboard, then remove it. But that doesn't remove the error, just works for a while till it blacks out again.

Comment: Are you working on real Mac or virtual machine? I'm working on vritual machine and I have a feeling that this is the "clue" of problem.

Comment: I'm working on both, but it only happend on the virtual machine

Comment: So it must be something with updating the system in the virtual environment.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me when i opened an xcode 5 project in xcode 6.

Here is my solution: what was causing the problem is a disrupted storyboard file. So i deleted the 2 folders of xuserdata in the project package and workspace package (so i reset what files opens when i launch the project just for convenience). and i edited the storyboard file xml header to match the same header of an xcode 6 made storyboard.

Comment: The problems seems to be coming back, i don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

Add your Apple account in Xcode -> Preference -> Account help solved this.

Answer (score 0):

On Xcode Interface builder, select correct orientation from below preview devices. This worked for me as my app orientation was locked landscape. Rotating preview made all things visible on storyboard